# SQL Server "update" - is there a race condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, race-condition

I have a table where I want to process a record on-demand given its ID. I only want to process each record once (when it is requested by a client).

`update my_table set pending_flag = 1 where my_table_id = 33 and pending_flag = 0`

When I run this query, it returns the number of records affected, either `1` or `0`.

**Is it safe to assume that running this query will only return `1` a maximum of 1 time, ever? If so, can I use this command alone as a mechanism to guarantee that I don't process the record multiple times?**

Additional details:

- `pending_flag` will never be set back to `0`
- multiple threads may be involved (as always)
- if the process that sets `pending_flag` to 1 does not complete, and that ID is essentially stuck in a "pending" state and screwed up forever, that is acceptable (but not ideal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `my_table_id` is the primary key of your table (i.e. the primary key constraint is set), then indeed it is impossible that you would have 2 rows affected by that update statement.

Through locking, the database engine ensures that a row is updated by one process at a time. At no moment in time will there be two records with the same value for `my_table_id`, since the primary key constraint forbids such a situation.

Secondly, as you update the flag `pending_flag` to 1, the record will not match if you run the same `update` statement again, and so 0 records will have been updated.

> can I use this command alone as a mechanism to guarantee that I don't process the record multiple times?

Yes! (with condition that you have `my_table_id` as the primary key or at least with a unique constraint).

Comment: I think the important part here is whether locks will ensure two distinct processes both issuing this statement "at the same time" won't both get 1.

Comment: This works regardless of indexing as well. Rows are U-locked to test them and the lock is held if the test succeeds.

Comment: Yes there is a race but only one winner and an update lock even block a read.  So the second will simply not find the record as pending_flag is 1.

Answer (score 1):

I see no guarantees on the sql server side. Nothing that prevents setting this flag back 0 by accident or programm error.  You may wish to add a trigger that prohibits any updates of the flag when it's set to 1.

Currently the only server guarantee is that only one of concurrent processes trying to set 0 -> 1 will succeed.